# How to intercept the access to a file in a .NET Program

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, file-access

I need to intercept when the system tries to access to a file, and do something before it happens.

Comment: I could swear this question was just asked recently, but I can't find it.

Comment: Have you looked at the FileSystemWatcher class?

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher gives me post-access, i need to have pre-access

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) - but this doesn't let you intercept the event and do things before hand - it only informs you after the fact that a particular file or directory has been affected in some way.

Intercepting file access is not something you can do easily.

You can write a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790748.aspx), which is an unmanaged DLL which the O/S will load that can [intercept operations on files or folders](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx). However, this isn't a trivial task.

What are you trying to achieve, perhaps there's a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Using just .net it is impossible

Answer (score 2):

Check http://easyhook.codeplex.com/, it provides you directly from c# c++ like dll method overwritting.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very similar thread here: [How could I prevent a folder from being created using a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297595/how-could-i-prevent-a-folder-from-being-created-using-a-windows-service/2297691#2297691). It may provide some more insight, but @LBushkin has already provided the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. What kind of access? Read, write, delete, copy?

- If you need to prevent access to a file then the security would be the way. Then you can capture the access and do delegate the task to a higher privileged execution engine. Such as a service running as higher privileged user.
- If you want to stop system level access then you'll need an [IFS filter](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).
- If all access is via your code, then I'd suggest a library that prevent's access.
- And as other people have mentioned, there is the FileSystemWatcher, but I think this post access not before.