# How to copy a file prior to being deleted

Tags: c#, .net, file, copy, filesystemwatcher

I would like to make a backup when a filen is deleted - or actually prior to being deleted.

I tried using the FileSystemWatcher but it only raises an event when the file is already deleted, making it impossible to copy the file.

Heres the code I tried:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\folderToWatch");

//watcher.Changed += WatchEvent;
//watcher.Created += WatchEvent;
//watcher.Renamed += WatchEvent;
watcher.Deleted += WatchEvent;

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

With the WatchEvent method as follows:

```
private static void WatchEvent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(@"C:\folderToWatchBackup", e.Name));

    Console.WriteLine($"{e.FullPath} was {e.ChangeType}");
}
```

Ofcourse it throws an exception when trying to copy the file that was already deleted.

I also tried listen on the Changed and Renamed events but they do not do the job either.

The perfect scenario would be an event like so:

```
watcher.BeforeDelete += WatchEvent;
```

I would like some suggestions on how to implement the wanted functionality or maybe some ideas that could point me in the direction of something useful.

While googling around all I found was to write something in C or C++ so maybe this really is an impossible task for C#?

(This is my first question so I hope it makes sense).

Comment: I don't know, but it may be too much to ask for a system-level solution in C#.  Perhaps you could surface some UI with its own file browser - in which case you could easily tap into such events..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# File change/create/delete event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047522/c-sharp-file-change-create-delete-event)

Comment: The answer in the dupe marked above details writing a filter driver, which would achieve what you want. As said in that answer though, it's not for the faint-hearted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible as most events will trigger AFTER your file is already deleted. I think your best bet is to run an `OnChanged` event instead. While this is not an ideal solution it does allow you to have the latest metadata of the file from when it was last changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Deleted` event means that the event is raised after deletion.

Because there is no `Deleting` event, you can't do what you want to do, as I know.

Perhaps with some kernel WinAPI...